# Getting the activated or focused window or form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-4.0

I want to get the width and height of the activated window, i have to move the cursor on that

window from X => 0 to X => width of activated window and same as for window height.

I am working on windows application using c#

Comment: But is the window of the C# application or not? Beacuse if it is, it's very simple, there are properties of the Windows...so it seems a little bit strange your question

Comment: well assume that it is c# window..

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
int w =this.Width;
int h = this.Height;
```

above code would give you height and with of current form

and you can set mouse position like below

```
MousePosition = new Point(w,h);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But there is some other problem is work only for one form. Now say that i have 3 forms on which or on any form that is activated, have to move the cursor then what i should to do, should i have to write these code lines on each form ? i want to handle from a single place.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Form.ActiveForm Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx)

```
Form currentForm = Form.ActiveForm;

int formWidth = currentForm.Width;
int formHeight = currentForm.Height;
```